# Infinite divisibility of a binomial random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, binomial-distribution

I am trying to figure whether or not the binomial distribution is infinitely divisible. As binomial random variables are bounded I believe that they are not infinitely divisible, but I am unsure how to prove this properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only  infinitely divisible distributions with compact support are the degenerate ones. In particular if $X$ takes only finite number of values and if $X$ is not a constant then it cannot be  infinitely divisible.

No bounded random variable is infinitely divisible. Proof: Suppose $|X| \leq M$ and $X$ is infinitely divisible. For any $n$ we can find i.i.d. random variables $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ such that $X_1+X_2+...+X_n$ has the same distribution as $X$. We have $0=P(X>M)\geq P(X_1 >\frac M n,X_2 >\frac M n,...X_n >\frac M n) =(P(X_1 >\frac M n))^{n}$ so $X_1 \leq \frac M n$ almost surely. Similarly $X_1 \geq -\frac M n$ almost surely. So $|X_1| \leq \frac M n$ almost surely and $var (X_1) \leq \frac {M^{2}} {n^{2}}$. Since  $var (X)=nvar(X_1)$ we see that $var X \leq \frac {M^{2}} n$. This is true for any $n$ so $var (X)=0$. This implies that  $X$ is a constant.

Comment: Why is this the case?

Comment: @MKXCVII I have added  a proof.

Comment: (a) How did you obtain the equality $P(X_1 >\frac M n,X_2 >\frac M n,...X_n >\frac M n) =(P(X_1 >\frac M n))^{n}$? While $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent, they are not necessarily identically distributed, but it seems like you've used that $X_i\sim X_1$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$. (b) And can we generalize this result to the case of a random variable taking values in a normed space? Depending on your answer to (a), we might can do the same as you did but consider $P(\left\|X\right\|>M)$ instead of $P(X>M)$ (which doesn't make sense in a general normed space).

Comment: 1) The definition of infinite divisibility involves i.i.d. random variables. 2)Yes, bounded r.v.'s with values in  normed linear spaces are not infinite divisible.  @0xbadf00d

Comment: (a) Yes, sorry, you're right. (b) How do we need to change the first inequality in that case?

Comment: If $f$ is a continuous linear functional then $f(X)$ is a bounded infinite divisible r.v. so it is almost surely constant. @0xbadf00d

Comment: It seems like something went wrong at the end of your proof. You wrote that "we see that $\operatorname{Var}[X_1]\le\frac{M^2}n$" (which is wrong), but what you've really shown is $\operatorname{Var}[X]\le\frac{M^2}n$ (which is precisely what we need). Since $n$ was arbitrary, it follows that $X$ is a.s. constant.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Thanks.  I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Regarding the generalization to a normed space $E$: You are using that $C_b(E)$ is point separating, right? If $A$ is an event with positive probability and $x:=X(\omega_1)\ne X(\omega_2)=:y$ for some $\omega_i\in A$, then there is a $f\in C_b(E)$ with $f(x)\ne f(y)$. But since $f(X)$ is a.s. constant, this is a contradiction. The only thing which isn't immediate to me is why $f(X)$ is infinitely divisible as well. Is any measurable transformation of $X$ infinitely divisible or is continuity important here?

Comment: I'd still be interested in whether you've got some much more simple argument in mind.