# Non-integer exponent convolution of measures

Tags: probability, measure-theory, fourier-transform, convolution, characteristic-functions

**Quick summary and notation.** Provided we have some measure $\mu$ on the Borel space $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, one can define an $n$-fold convolution measure $\mu \ast \cdots \ast \mu$ on $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ by evaluating each $A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ as follows.
$$ \big(\mu \ast \cdots \ast \mu\big)(A) = \int_{\mathbb{R^d}}\cdots \int_{\mathbb{R^d}} 1_A(x_1 + \cdots + x_n) \mu({\rm d}x_1) \cdots \mu({\rm d}x_n)  $$
By Fubini, this object $\mu_n = \mu \ast \cdots \ast \mu$ too is a measure, and its characteristic function $\hat\mu_n$ has a very nice form in terms of that $\hat\mu$ of $\mu$.
$$\begin{aligned}
  \hat\mu_n(u) 
  &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \exp\langle iu,x\rangle \mu_n({\rm d}x) \\
  &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \cdots \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\exp\langle iu, x_1 + \cdots + x_n\rangle \mu({\rm d}x_1) \cdots \mu({\rm d}x_n) \\
  &= \bigg( \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \exp\langle iu, x \rangle \mu({\rm d}x) \bigg)^n \\
  &= \big(\mu(u)\big)^n
\end{aligned}$$

This is a nice homomorphism between measures and their characteristic functions.
$$ \widehat{\mu \ast \mu} = \hat\mu \cdot \hat\mu$$

> **My question.** Provided some measure $\mu$ and positive real number $r > 0$, can I guarantee some measure $\mu_r$ with characteristic function being the corresponding exponential?
> $$ \hat\mu_r(u) = \big(\mu(u)\big)^r $$

Surely, there are some cases in which this is obvious, like $\mu$ being degenerate or belonging to some nice exponential family of probability measures.
I simply wonder if there is a general result for all (probability) measures $\mu$.
Also, it seems like the comprehensive theory of Fourier transforms on the Schwartz class and tempered distributions might lend itself somewhere, but my knowledge is very weak in this area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Setting $r = \frac{1}{n}$ this would imply that $\mu$ is itself the $n$-fold convolution of some other measure $\mu_{\frac{1}{n}}$; for probability measures this property is called [infinite divisibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability)) and it generally does not hold. For example, the uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$ is not infinitely divisible; the Wikipedia article says this follows from the fact that it has bounded support (but I don't know off the top of my head why this is enough).

Comment: That makes so much sense. Thank you!

Comment: > I don't know off the top of my head why this is enough. \\

Same here. But I looked up on this site and [found this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3569018/8157) of Kavi Rama Murthy. Let $\mu$ be supported on $[0,1]$ and assume by contradiction that $X\sim \mu$ is infinitely divisible. Then there are iid $X_1\ldots X_n$ such that $\sum X_j\sim X$.  But then $0=P(X>1)=(P(X_1>1/n))^n$, so $X_1>1/n$ almost surely. Letting $n\to \infty$ we reach a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, there's an obvious typo in my previous comment, it is $X_1\le 1/n$ almost surely, not $X_1>1/n$.

Comment: @Giuseppe: $X_1 \le \frac{1}{n}$ almost surely by itself isn't a contradiction; $X_1$ depends on $n$, it's not the same random variable for all $n$. But I see that the full argument concludes with a bound on $X$ itself, which makes more sense.